# Iterate two lists and find matches

Tags: java, iteration

I have 2 lists with varying length. Both lists contain data which has to be matched with entries from the other list. Currently I am iterating both lists with a nested `for-loop`.

```
List<MyClass1> list2 = myClass1dao.findUnmatchedEntries();
List<MyClass2> list1 = myClass2dao.findUnmatchedEntries();

for (MyClass2 list1entry : list1) {
    for (MyClass1 list2entry : list2) {
        if (list1entry.getName().equals(list2entry.getName())
            && list1entry.getID().equals(list2entry.getID())) {
            //update entries
            myClass2dao.update(list1entry);
            myClass1dao.update(list2entry);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this takes exponentially longer the more elements each list has.

So my question is, how can this code be improved?

Note: I am on a java 7 code base so answers to java 7 are preferred, but java 8 is okay as well

Comment: What's the nature of the condition? Does it involve both list elements or is it unrelated?

Comment: It includes elements from both lists

Comment: If your class's equals method returns true if names are equal you could use the built in list.retailAll(list2). This operation would probably be a lot faster if you used sets instead of lists too. The copying of elements to make a set might not be worth it though

Comment: @chatton This is sadly not an option. I think I have to iterate both lists like this

Comment: As you are dealing with lists the resulting algorithm complexity will be `O(n*m)`. For better performance compose and return maps from `findUnmatchedEntries()` and use them in your names comparison mechanism. Use `names` as map keys and class (MyClass1 and MyClass2) objects as map values.

Comment: If performance is an issue: Perform the conditions in the backend.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Since the IF is not just for the `names`, I would need to build a separate class which holds all the criteria. When fetching from database I would need to transform the list into the map, which in java7 requires to iterate the list. And the `containsKey` method iterates the map as well. I doubt there is a performance improevment

Comment: @slowy you mean in the database fetch?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes. There's no reason to load a set of data which is not needed. Ah and also: Perform batch updates, instead of potentially updating every loop.

Comment: I am using `hibernate` for database communication. From my understanding, the updates are only executed as soon as the method finishes (therefore batch-update). I don't think I can move the condition into the SELECT (at least it wouldn't make much sense), because I still have to iterate the results to perform the actual matching

Comment: "I know that this takes exponentially longer the more elements each list has." No, this is quadratic in the length of each list. This approach will scale pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly consider adding a `Comparable` abstract class with two implementations (one containing a `MyClass1`, and the other a `MyClass2`). At that point you can use all the normal collection framework methods to process this. Alternatively you could transform both sets into something like `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,List<MyClassX>>>`, then just lookup by the name and id.

Additionally, if the lists are sorted, we could do this much more efficiently, by getting two iterators, then simply getting the next element of the one that is behind at each stage.

Comment: "_...we could do this much more efficiently, but getting two iterators, then simply..._" - should the word *but* have actually been *by*?

Answer (score 0):

I assume both lists contain object of the same type/class, ie MyClass1 and MyClass2 are not two different classes.

In such a case MyClass can override equals method. Once equals is implemented as stated & you have ensured not to have violated the equals and hashcode contract, you can the use a HashMap.

This can reduce your time complexity.

Comment: The reason i named them differntly here is because htey are different classes

Comment: If name+id concatenated can be unique, then create a hashmap<string, string> or Set ?